# dropdown options change based on another dropdowns choices

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form that has several dropdowns. I need to make the second dependent on the value of the first. I have a Codepen that shows four dropdowns. The first does not change but the selects 2, 3, and 4 show the intended options I want. 
Here is a listing of what option of dropdown 1 leads to the second.

```
new -> input-2
client -> input-3
admin -> input-4
```

I am doing this in OpenCart in a MVC so I am a little confused if this all is done in the view file or do I need to have some of this done in the controller, and if so how? I do believe JavaScript would be able to help here but not really sure how to implement that. My code pen is:

https://codepen.io/anon_guy/pen/pdbYad

```
<form action="/action_page.php">

  <select name="Input-1">
    <option value="*"></option>
    <option value="new">new</option>
    <option value="client">client</option>
    <option value="admin">admin</option>  
  </select>

  <select name="Input-2">
    <option value="sign-up">Sign Up</option>  
  </select>

  <select name="Input-3">
    <option value="upgrade">upgrade</option>  
    <option value="stats">stats</option>  
  </select>

  <select name="Input-4">
    <option value="view-accounts">view all</option>  
    <option value="add">add</option>  
     <option value="remove">remove</option>  
  </select>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: So you want to hide dropdown 2, 3 and 4 on default value of dp 1, show the 2nd if dp 1 value is "new", show the 3rd if the value of dp 1 is "client" and show the 4th if the value of the dp 1 is "admin"?

Comment: I think I found an answer not sure if this is good check out this codpen:  https://codepen.io/anon_guy/pen/XzKQKw

Comment: be aware of the default value. It is not reset if the empty value is chosen.